# MVC TextBoxFor onfocus style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm not very skillful with HTML, but I want to change the style when a TextBoxFor got the focus.
I tried this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre, new { id = "fname", onfocus="setStyle(this.id)" })
```

But I'm getting an error.
What should I do?

Comment: Why are you setting the id of this control? TextBoxFor will define the ID based on the expression creating the TextBox (in this case, the id will be "Nombre")

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is not like ASP.NET in many ways, really... I don't think "onfocus='setStyle(this.id)'" is doing what you think it's going, unless "setStyle(...)" is a JavaScript function on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css:

```
input[type=text]:focus
{
    background:red;
}
```

For :focus to work in IE8, a !DOCTYPE must be declared.